# Excel VBA - Pass a Row of Cell Values to an Array and then Paste that Array to a Relative Reference of Cells

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Using Excel (2010) VBA, I am trying to copy (pass) a constant range of cells (whose values recalculate) to an array.  Then I am trying to pass that array to a new range of cells, directly below it.  After I have done this, I want to again copy (pass) the constant range's new values to the array, and pass these new values to a range directly below the one I previously passed.

I know this code is atrocious (I am new to arrays in VBA).

```
Sub ARRAYER()

Dim anARRAY(5) As Variant

Number_of_Sims = 10

For i = 1 To Number_of_Sims
   anARRAY = Range("C4:G4")
   Range("C4").Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(Number_of_Sims, 0).Select
   ActiveCell = anARRAY
   Range("C4").Select
Next

End Sub
```

I sure do appreciate your help!

Thank you.

Respectfully,

Jonathan

Comment: Why do you want to use an array? Am I correct in understanding that you want to copy the (changing) values into C4:G4 into the row below?

Comment: Hi Jonathon, can you pls add an example of what you are doing, perhaps a screenshot? It isn't clear to me (at least)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are off slightly on a few things here, so hopefully the following helps.

Firstly, you don't need to select ranges to access their properties, you can just specify their address etc.  Secondly, unless you are manipulating the values within the range, you don't actually need to set them to a variant.  If you do want to manipulate the values, you can leave out the bounds of the array as it will be set when you define the range.

It's also good practice to use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules to force variable declaration.

The following will do what you are after:

```
Sub ARRAYER()
    Dim Number_of_Sims As Integer, i As Integer

    Number_of_Sims = 10

    For i = 1 To Number_of_Sims
       'Do your calculation here to update C4 to G4
       Range(Cells(4 + i, "C"), Cells(4 + i, "G")).Value = Range("C4:G4").Value
    Next
End Sub
```

If you do want to manipulate the values within the array then do this:

```
Sub ARRAYER()
    Dim Number_of_Sims As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim anARRAY as Variant

    Number_of_Sims = 10

    For i = 1 To Number_of_Sims
       'Do your calculation here to update C4 to G4
       anARRAY= Range("C4:G4").Value

       'You can loop through the array and manipulate it here

       Range(Cells(4 + i, "C"), Cells(4 + i, "G")).Value = anARRAY
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Cuber Chase!  Using your answer and Chuff's, I'm getting a better understanding of this.  I really do appreciate it.

Comment: No worries :). Using arrays is almost always faster and beneficial than working directly with ranges. It's a good habit to get into.

Comment: In line 3 of the second block, you are missing a space character.

Answer (score 3):

No need for array. Just use something like this:

```
Sub ARRAYER()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Number_of_Sims As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Number_of_Sims = 10

    Set Rng = Range("C4:G4")
    For i = 1 To Number_of_Sims
       Rng.Offset(i, 0).Value = Rng.Value
       Worksheets("Sheetname").Calculate   'replacing Sheetname with name of your sheet
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Chuff.  The reason I'm looking to use an array is because currently I'm running about 10,000 - 100,000 simulations.  Currently, I'm just copying the range, and then pasting it in the right place using Active Cell Offset.  I really appreciate the advice.  Just one question, would this work as fast as an array?

I'm trying to get my run time down from 1 hour to 5 to 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are copying tha same data to all rows, you don't actually need to loop at all.  Try this:

```
Sub ARRAYER()
    Dim Number_of_Sims As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Number_of_Sims = 100000

    Set rng = Range("C4:G4")
    rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Number_of_Sims) = rng.Value

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When i Tried your Code i got en Error when i wanted to fill the Array.

you can try to fill the Array like This.

```
Sub Testing_Data()
Dim k As Long, S2 As Worksheet, VArray

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set S2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
With S2
    VArray = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
End With
For k = 2 To UBound(VArray, 1)
    S2.Cells(k, "B") = VArray(k, 1) / 100
    S2.Cells(k, "C") = VArray(k, 1) * S2.Cells(k, "B")
Next

End Sub
```