# VBA Excel loop with offset for extended range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,

I've made the loop for the range, which is copied from one sheet to another. However, I have no solution for trimming my code down, which looks like this:

```
 Sub sunrise()
Dim i As Single
With Worksheets("7")
.UsedRange.Clear
.Range("a1").Value = "Latitude"
.Range("b1").Value = "-18"
.Range("c1").Value = "-17"
.Range("d1").Value = "-16"
.Range("e1").Value = "-15"
.Range("f1").Value = "-14"
.Range("g1").Value = "-13"
.Range("h1").Value = "-12"
.Range("i1").Value = "-11"
.Range("j1").Value = "-10"
.Range("k1").Value = "-9"
.Range("l1").Value = "-8"
.Range("m1").Value = "-7"
.Range("n1").Value = "-6"
.Range("o1").Value = "-5"
.Range("p1").Value = "-4"
.Range("q1").Value = "-3"
.Range("r1").Value = "-2"
.Range("s1").Value = "-1"
.Range("t1").Value = "-0.85"
.Range("u1").Value = "0.6"
.Range("v1").Value = "1.7"
.Range("w1").Value = "2.76"
.Range("x1").Value = "3.84"

 For i = 48 To 60 Step 0.25
    Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("A2").Value = i '* (-1)
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = i
    .Offset(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("E742").Value
    .Offset(1, 2).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("F742").Value
    .Offset(1, 3).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("G742").Value
    .Offset(1, 4).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("H742").Value
    .Offset(1, 5).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("I742").Value
    .Offset(1, 6).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("J742").Value
    .Offset(1, 7).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("K742").Value
    .Offset(1, 8).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("L742").Value
    .Offset(1, 9).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("M742").Value
    .Offset(1, 10).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("N742").Value
    .Offset(1, 11).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("O742").Value
    .Offset(1, 12).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("P742").Value
    .Offset(1, 13).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("Q742").Value
    .Offset(1, 14).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("R742").Value
    .Offset(1, 15).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("S742").Value
    .Offset(1, 16).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("T742").Value
    .Offset(1, 17).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("U742").Value
    .Offset(1, 18).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("V742").Value
    .Offset(1, 19).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("W742").Value
    .Offset(1, 20).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("X742").Value
    .Offset(1, 21).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("Y742").Value
    .Offset(1, 22).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("Z742").Value
    .Offset(1, 23).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("AA742").Value
    End With
  Next I
 End With
```

End Sub

I wish I could assign these values in the arrays, as shown in the example below:

[Excel VBA - Pass a Row of Cell Values to an Array and then Paste that Array to a Relative Reference of Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794556/excel-vba-pass-a-row-of-cell-values-to-an-array-and-then-paste-that-array-to-a)

but in my event the `i` appears as a single value and is allocated separately for the particular row, defined above.

[image]

I was also thinking about the solution like this:

```
   .Offset(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("1. GENERAL").Range("E742:AA742").Value
```

Is there any way to trim down this code?

Comment: Your last suggestion is on the right lines, just need to add `resize` after the `offset`.

Comment: **NEVER** use floating point types (e.g. double and single) as loop counters. Due to rounding errors the loop might terminate earlier or later than you think and you will be scratching your head for a month before you're able to figure out what's causing your error. This was an advice from my professor and I always remember it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next approach, please. It will copy the range, to the last empty row (calculated for A:A), starting from B column:

```
Sub testCopyArray()
 Dim sh7 As Worksheet, shG As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, rng As Range
 
 Set sh = Worksheets("7")
 Set shG = Worksheets("1. GENERAL")
  lastRow = sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)
  Set rng = sh.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)

  rng.Offset(1).Value = 1
  sh.Range(rng.Offset(1, 1), rng.Offset(1, 21)).Value = shG.Range("E742:Y742").Value
  'or:
  rng.Offset(1,1).Resize(,shG.Range("E742:Y742").columns).value = shG.Range("E742:Y742").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, but I need 2 sheets in the code. One is "1. GENERAL", another one is "7".

Comment: @MKR: This is only an example. But, OK, I will adapt the code for both your sheets... Adapted it.

Comment: @MKR: Did you find some time to test the above code, please? Does it work as you need?

Comment: @MKR: But what do you need to accomplish in your code, using the iteration? Do you only need to copy the "E742:Y742" range once, at the first empty row, or you need to fill more rows and also increment the copied range ("E743:Y743", "E744:Y744", "E745:Y745" and so on...)?

Comment: I will test your code next time (within 2 hours I believe). For now, I used the @SJR solution and it works. I have got in 1st row the following columns -18,-17-16... and up to +4. Next in the following row I want to fill up the corresponding values, as you see in the image (Sheet2).